# Error message from including luacode package in Overleaf

Tags: luatex, overleaf, luacode

I am including the LuaTeX into an Overleaf LaTeX document by

```
\usepackage{arxiv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Sharelatex Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
```

but encountered the following error message:

> Package luacode Error:
> /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty,
> line 51 LuaTeX is required for this package. Aborting..
>
> See the luacode package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.51     to prevent additional errors.}
> This package can only be used with the LuaTeX engine (command `lualatex'). Package loading has been
> stopped to prevent additional errors.

What is the remedy?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compile the file with `pdfTeX` instead of `luaTeX`.

Comment: You need to change your compiler to LuaLaTeX, see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Changing_compiler for how to do that. Note that since Lua(La)TeX handles fonts very differently from pdf(La)TeX there are a few packages you should not load with LuaLaTeX (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28642/35864, some of the advice there is outdated, `babel` for example works fine with modern LuaLaTeX): Do not load `inputenc` and `fontenc` with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: With LuaLaTeX you'll want to drop `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. No matter what compiler you use you should make sure that `hyperref` is the last package you load (save for a few exceptions). There is little point in loading `\usepackage{url}` if you also load `\usepackage{hyperref}` (since the latter loads the former), especially if you do it after loading `hyperref`. (These hints won't help with the error message you posted, but they are still relevant for your document.)

Comment: @moewe: Thank you. Changing to LuaLaTeX helped. But dropping '\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}' generated hundreds of warnings like Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character `\r A' in font encoding `TU' in inheritance list `microtype.cfg/358(protrusion)'.  and it lost the styles for the large and bold font for section titles.

Comment: As I said, the way fonts are handled in pdf(La)TeX and Lua(La)TeX is quite different. So it may not be enough to just drop `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243482/35864. In any case `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is detrimental with LuaLaTeX as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470976/35864 (compile `\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Grüße
\end{document}` with LuaLaTeX to see a very obvious problem)

Comment: @moewe: OK. I have replaced 'fontenc' with 'fontspec' and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `luacode` you need to compile your document with LuaLaTeX (and not with pdfLaTeX, which is probably the standard in most editors, or XeLaTeX).

See https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Changing_compiler for how to do that on Overleaf.

---

Note that pdf(La)TeX and Lua(La)TeX handle fonts very differently, that means that you may have to change a few things in your preamble when you switch to LuaLaTeX. (Cf. also [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28642/35864))

In particular

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

should not be loaded with LuaLaTeX. Instead most people will load

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

See [Switching to lualatex: How to translate font setups?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243482/35864) and [Are there cases where fontenc + luatex (or xetex) cause problems?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470976/35864) for details and background.