# How can I select Cambria or Calibri fonts in Overleaf (for Greek language)?

Tags: fonts

I can't find a way to use the Cambria or Calibri fonts in LateX. How do I change fonts in LaTeX in general?

In Microsoft Word e.g. there is an infinite number of font options. Is this true for LaTeX, too,  or does it just have a specific number of available fonts? In addition to that, why do I have a problem changing the font for the Greek language?

Comment: This is a very general question that can easily answered by a simple search … That said: If you want to use any font (just like in MS Word), there is really no easy alternative to either `XeLaTeX` or (preferably) `LuaLaTeX`. Otherwise you are pretty much limited to the LaTeX font catalogue (https://tug.org/FontCatalogue)

Comment: @Ingmar What  additional knowledge does using lualatex or xelatex require? I mean what is the difference between them and the conventional pdflatex?

Comment: It's really not all that different. This should get you started: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243482

Comment: In Overleaf, find the right drop.down menu and select LuaLaTeX instead of the default pdfLaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither Calibri nor Cambria are installed in the Overleaf system. So if you want to use them, you will need to upload them to your project folder assuming you have a licence for them that allows this. Then if you compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you should be able to use them. As for changing the font for Greek, you should use `babel` or `polyglossia` and set the fonts for the language using the methods described in their documentation.

There are clones of these fonts installed on TeXLive (and therefore Overleaf) The Cambria clone called `Caladea`  and the Calibri clone is called `Carlito`. Both can be loaded with `fontspec` and compiled using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.  To use these fonts with `babel` you load them with the `\babelfont` command.  But unlike actual Cambria, the Caladea font doesn't contain Greek as far as I can tell. Here's an example of how to use both English and Greek, but due to the font limitation, the Greek will be in the Calibri clone.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Caladea}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{Carlito} % this makes the “roman” font sans in Greek
\babelfont[greek,english]{sf}{Carlito}
\begin{document}
Some English roman text. 

\textsf{Some English sans text}


\selectlanguage{greek}
Αυτό είναι ένα ελληνικό κείμενο.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: er you can use the chromefonts clones (which are installed) OP probably doesn't  have a licence to upload Cambria to overleaf (as it's linux)

Comment: After switching overleaf to lualatex compiler when I try to type greek ,the greek text does not even appear (even with the default latex font) and I have tried both babel and polyglossia packages. Any Ideas what is going wrong? Thanks

Comment: @KaniPen I've updated the code example.