# How to generate PDF/X-4 files?

Tags: tufte, pdfx

I'm in middle of fine tuning my thesis for printing. I'm using the beautiful `tufte-latex` class and I complile with `LuaLatex`. The printing press has asked for a `PDF/X-4` if possible, and seeing that this is considered a standard of sorts I want to comply. I've done some googling but haven't found the "definate guide" as of yet. Any idea where to begin?

Comment: Related: [How to generate PDF/A and PDF/X?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/576) - although X-4 is probably too new to ask. Your best choice may be a commercial conversion program (like Adobe Acrobat).

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/242314/37364) might provide starting point.