# Unknown option `x-1a1' for package `pdfx' error

Tags: xetex, pdftex, pdfx

I am trying to use `pdfx` package to generate PDF/X-1a:2001. According to [its specification](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf):

> The package can be loaded with the command:
>
> `\usepackage[<option>]{pdfx}`

and

> `x-1a`: generate PDF/X-1a. Options `x-1a1` and `x-1a3` are also available to specify PDF/X-1a:2001 or PDF/X-1a:2003 explicitly.

So using that information my document source is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[x-1a1]{pdfx}
\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

After compiling with `pdflatex` (`TeX Live 2013/Debian` distribution) I get following error:

```
LaTeX Error: Unknown option `x-1a1' for package `pdfx'
```

Same happens for `xelatex` (`TeX Live 2013/Debian`) which I need to use to compile actual document.

When I tried compiling same document on `MiKTeX 2.9` it compiled with `pdflatex`.

Why are `pdfx` options not recognized by `TeX Live 2013/Debian` distribution?

Comment: See the change history: The manual states that some more variants were added with version 1.5.4, apparently `x-1a1` is one of them. The latest version is `1.5.4` and this is from February 2015. You need to update your TeXLive. I can compile your example with `pdflatex`, the `xelatex` stuff is another issue, in fact

Comment: I am assuming that by "No need to update your TeX Live" you actually mean "You need to update TeX Live". Right?

Comment: Right, it was a typo. Please update your distribution. Thanks for notifying me about the typo

Comment: So updating TeX Live will allow me to compile it with ``pdflatex``, but I still won't be able to use ``xelatex`` (which is requirment for me). Is it impossible to use ``pdfx`` with ``xelatex`` at all?

Comment: Yes, `pdflatex` works on my Linux with TL 2015, `xelatex` fails, but I don't know why. Perhaps there is a work around

Comment: You can control the output version with `pdf14`, `pdf15`, `pdf16` and `pdf17` options

Comment: Apparently, `XeLaTeX` doesn't define `\pdfminorversion`

Comment: From the documentation of the package:
> This package currently supports generation of PDF/X and PDF/A compliant documents using PDF TEX.

Comment: You can't use it with XeLaTeX. You have to choose: one or the other but not both. If XeLaTeX is required, you'll have to remove `pdfx`.

Comment: @cfr Do you know of any other way (that is, without using ``pdfx`` package) to generate PDF/X compliant document with XeLaTeX? I need to use OTF font, but at the same time I have to generate PDF/X document; I can't give up either one. (I asked new question for that: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255480/producing-pdf-x-compliant-document-with-xelatex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pdfx` package only supports `pdflatex` compilation. In order to use `xelatex` for compilation, you can follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275914/37364). Please note that it would be good idea to update your distribution to TeXLive 2015 before following this answer, since otherwise your resulting PDF file might not validate fully, as mentioned [in this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255480/producing-pdf-x-compliant-document-with-xelatex/275914#comment723113_275914).

If you are willing to switch to LuaLaTeX, solution shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/242314/37364) will work for you.