# Producing PDF/X compliant document with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, pdfx

## Solution

Full solution for producing PDF/X compliant document can be found in MWE and answer to this question: [Disabling all document interactivity (for PDF/X compliance)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300506/disabling-all-document-interactivity-for-pdf-x-compliance)

Adapted MWE and compilation method are taken from Leonid's answer to this question.

Please note that solution requires compilation with TeXLive 2015 (or later).

## Original question

I am trying to compile my source with XeLaTeX to produce PDF/X-1a:2001 compliant document. Getting PDF/X-1a:2001 is possible with `pdfx` package (while using up-to-date TeX distribution), but only when document is compiled with `pdflatex`.

Since I am using OTF and TTF fonts in my document, I have to use XeLaTeX to compile it. This is MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[x-1a1]{pdfx}
\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this document with MiKTeX's 2.9 `xelatex` I get following error and compilation halts:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.111 \pdfminorversion
                      =4 %  assumed for PDF/A ;  options may change this for...

?
```

Is there any way to compile PDF/X-1a:2001 with XeLaTeX, either using `pdfx` or different package?

Ps. I used `MiKTeX 2.9`, because I don't want to update my `TeX Live 2013/Debian` distribution I normally use. With MiKTeX I get most recent version of `pdfx` package.

**EDIT:** Since it isn't obvious from Leonid's answer and is mentioned only in comments, please note that **you need TeXLive 2015 in order for Leonid's answer to work fully**. TeXLive 2013 (installed by your system's package manager) or MiKTeX 2.9 won't do the trick (this is true as of March 2016; it might change by the time you read this).

---

I also tried to compile this MWE with `LuaLaTeX` to see if this works. It didn't. I get following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pdfx@findUUID ... \pdfx@tmpstring {\pdfmdfivesum 
                                                  {#1}} \expandafter \pdfx@e...
l.360 \pdfx@findUUID{\jobname.pdf}

?
```

In the event version of LuaLaTeX matters: `lualatex --version` outputs

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013062821  (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (rev 4627)
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling with LuaTeX? `pdfx` is clearly designed only to support pdfTeX. However, it would be worth seeing what you get with LuaTeX, at least. To answer the question asked on your previous post, I'm not aware of a way to do this with XeTeX. But I use pdfTeX 99.999999999% of the time, so others are more likely to be aware of your options than I am.

Comment: @cfr I thought about it earlier, but unfortunately error is very similar to ``xelatex`` compilation. I updated my question to include that information.

Comment: Last time I checked this (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242303/pdf-x-1a-on-tex-live-2014-for-publishing-with-pod-lightining-source/242314#242314) worked with LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put some specific metadata inside resulting pdf with `\special` command, add some info with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package and then compile with xelatex option `-output-driver="xdvipdfmx -V 3"`. Look at example:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex 
%%%%Needs to be compiled with commandline: "xelatex.exe -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -V 3" %.tex" % as PDF 1.3 required by PDF/X
\documentclass{book}

%%%%%%%%% PDF-X stuff, IF USING xelatex %%%%%%%%%
%(mm size * 72)/25.4 = bp size
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipout{% %A hook that is executed for every page (after first one)
    \special{pdf: put @thispage
      <<
        /TrimBox [0 0 210.990 162.086] %put here other numbers = size of page in bp
      >>
    }
}
\special{pdf: put @thispage
  <<
    /TrimBox [0 0 210.990 162.086] %put here other numbers = size of page in bp
  >>
}
\special{pdf:docinfo
  <<
    /GTS_PDFXVersion (PDF/X-1:2001)
    /GTS_PDFXConformance (PDF/X-1a:2001)
  >>
}

\special{pdf:put @catalog
<<
  /PageMode /UseNone
  /OutputIntents [
    <<
      /Info (none)
      /Type /OutputIntent
      /S /GTS_PDFX
      /OutputConditionIdentifier (Custom)
      /RegistryName (http://www.color.org/)
    >>
  ]
>>
}%

\usepackage{datetime} % for \pdfdate command

\usepackage{hyperref} % for \hypersetup

\hypersetup{% 
    pdftitle={DocTitle},% PDF/X document should have a title
    pdfinfo={% Setting some more PDF/X stuff for xelatex
        ModDate={D:\pdfdate},% PDF/X document should have a modification date
        Trapped={False},% PDF/X document should have Trapped tag set
    },
}


\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Another example, compilable in `lualatex`, `pdflatex` and `xelatex`: http://gist.github.com/LSinev/98c0a40e94f4507922a8

Comment: Why the multiple iterations of `\hypersetup`? Normally, `hyperref` should be loaded late. Is there any particular reason to load it first here (e.g. before `datetime`)?

Comment: No particular reason in this case.
I would personally prefer to put all pdf/x code in one block, thus multiple hypersetup can help.

Comment: Updated example. Removed multiple ```\hypersetup```. Put [```hyperref```](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) after [```datetime```](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime)

Comment: @Leonid When I compile your MWE and then check against PDF/X-1a:2001 with Acrobat Pro DC, I get "Document ID missing" error and information that this is reason for document being non-compliant. Do you know how to add document ID, so that PDF validates fully?

Comment: @Rafal If you open resulting pdf in a notepad-like text editor you should see something like `<</Root 1 0 R/Info 2 0 R/ID[<2d23965234628620dad1b7e554d8ad45><2d23965234628620dad1b7e554d8ad45>]/Size` in last 10 lines of file. This is id. It is MD5 hash. It is changing each compile. I compiled with latest version of TeXLive 2015 packages.

Comment: I tested your MWE on ``TeX Live 2013/Debian`` and ``MiKTeX 2.9``. In both cases, opening resulting PDF in plain-text editor (I used Sublime Text and gedit) shows me human-unreadable groups of 4 digits, so I have no way of telling if that ID you mention is there. But even if it is, what is important is that Acrobat shows this "Document ID missing" error. Screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32919746/pdfx-acrobat.jpg. I was hoping there is some kind of "DocumentID" metadata (similar to ModDate) that can be added to MWE in order to avoid this lack of Document ID Acrobat is reporting.

Comment: Interesingly, when I save this PDF as PDF/X with Acrobat, plain text editor shows me readable data, including ID you mentioned, as well as Document ID included as XMP metadata ("xmpMM:DocumentID" tag) in the form of UUID identifier. And Acrobat does not complain about this file created by itself.

Comment: [hyperxmp package documentation](ftp://ftp.gust.org.pl/TeX/macros/latex/contrib/hyperxmp/hyperxmp.pdf) claims that it can add document identifier and shows source of package that defines DocumentID command, but has no example of how to use it.

Comment: @Rafal https://yadi.sk/i/ZDdFLF_Wq8hBX - test this file, compiled from this MWE. Still missing Document ID?

Comment: @Leonid Your file passed Acrobat check without an issue. So, it seems it is time for me to upgrade my TeXLive distribution.

Comment: @Rafal Try to add `\usepackage{hyperxmp}` just after `hyperref` call. Maybe this will help without upgraing.

Comment: @Leonid Just tried changing package load order and unfortunately it does not change anything. I hoped ``hyperxmp`` had command for Document ID, but it seems it does not.

Comment: This command is internal.At mine distribution it adds "xmpMM:DocumentID" tag without anything more than `\usepackage{hyperxmp}`.

Comment: @Leonid I now updated to TeXLive 2015 and PDF compiled from your MWE (without ``hyperxmp``) validates fully, so that's great. Problem arises when ``hyperref`` adds interactivity in some cases, as that obviously will break PDF/X compliance. (I asked separate question about it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300506/37364)

Comment: @Leonid Your suggestion works well, is it possible to fix `PDF-X1a` setting in `LaTeX -> dvips -> PS2PDF`, please suggest...

Comment: @MadyYuvi I have no idea. Both dvips and ps2pdf may strip some tags. So you can import pdf back to pdflatex with pdfpages and apply this solution. Or you can try to ask https://stackoverflow.com/q/30434868/6028129

Comment: @Leonid Thanks for your prompt reply....