# pdfx package fails with veraPDF and preflight does not support special characters (UTF-8 not used) and

Tags: pdfx

I finished (after a lot of work) my Ph.D. thesis in LaTeX. However, I got a big problem after I read that I have to submit the PDF as PDF/A file. First of all I tried to convert it by using the Acrobat Professional Software (the IT did it) but we failed. So I went a step back and tried to build the PDF/A file via LaTeX and came across the package pdfx. While using this package, I cannot use the `usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` based on the fact that it is a dependency of the `pdfx` package. However, after changing a few own commands and other math operators such as `\bullet`, which are already in use or do not exist anymore, I got the the problem that the umlaut `ä ü ö ß` are not working anymore.

**Update** this problem was related to a non-updated version of `pdfx package`. After the update, the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` can be used and everything works fine.

---

The second problem is that the generated pdf is not PDF/A conform. `preflight and veraPDF` gave a bunch of errors that I cannot handle. Any ideas.

---

I hope that someone can give me some advice.

Thanks in advance
Tobi

Comment: Since you have IT support with Acrobat Pro: Forget `pdfx` package. Re-compile your TeX using `lualatex`. You need to `\usepackage{fontenc}` and load fonts by the methods described in that package doc. You will also need to remove `inputenc` and `fontenc` because you will automatically be using UTF-8. If you can get it to compile and it looks good, then have IT convert to PDF/A using Acrobat Pro. At most you can get A-1b (not A-1a), after allowing the program to automatically add tags. Whether this method is an easy deal, or hard work, depends more on your use of fonts than on anything else.

Comment: @RobtAll fontspec not fontenc.

Comment: Oops! @TeXnician is correct. My typo, but I can't edit the first comment.

Comment: What is the problem if you activate inputenc? It works fine for me (in both locations).

Comment: @RobtAll, thank you for the hint with the `fontspec` and `lualatex`. I will check out the package and `lualatex` now. @Ulrike Fischer, if I activate the `inputenc` after `pdfx` I get a clash error.

Comment: Just one comment. If I activate `inputenc` before `pdfx`, everything compiles well and looks fine. However, the `verapdf` validator tells me that it is not `A-1b` conform. `fontspec` with `xelatex` gives me a bunch of error (just tried based on the fact that I saw that it works with `fontspec` too). I will check out `lualatex` during the day. By the way. It is my Ph.D. thesis and I hope that I do not have to change tooooo much in any case.

Comment: Is your system uptodate? What is the version of pdfx?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - nope :)  I just updated the pdfx package. I had an older version and now it is working with the `inputenc` package.
I also reduced my > 500.000 validation failed checks to 98 now. I think I am on the right way but I have to figure out how to deal with the other things. As `pdffonts` tell me, all fonts are embedded but I still get an error during validation by using `verapdf` (https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-validation-profiles/wiki/PDFA-Part-1-rules#rule-634-1) I will try to fix everything today. If it is not working, I try `lualatex` but I guess I got other problems then.

Comment: I tried out veraPDF a few weeks ago because of another question, (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402431/pdf-a-with-linux-libertine-und-linux-biolinum-using-pdflatex) and it complained about things where Adobe preflight didn't. I also had the impression that veraPDF is still under development. So I would check with adobe pro too.

Comment: Just want to update. I reduced a lot of errors in my PDFA while hacking the `pdfx` package. There is only one problem that I am trying to resolve and after that I will make a summary and the workaround I did to get it work. By the way, you are right. The `verapdf` is more strict than the one of adobe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Update: Patch for pdfx added at the bottom (23.02.2018)*

Today I made some investigation into the topic of PDF/A file generation with LaTeX and the `pdfx package` and figured out the solution. Actually I will present two versions and the validation check by using the `veraPDF` application. Okay lets start. The easiest way is to use Acrobat Professional (if it is available).

---

### **Using Acrobat Professional**

- Compile your LaTeX file as it is into a PDF
- Open the PDF on the computer with the installed Adobe software
- Print the file by using the `Adobe PDF` printer and choose the PDF/A option
- Check with `veraPDF` or `preflight` -> valid
- Done & happy

In my case I could not convert it directly because I got some errors. I have no idea why but the only possible way was the above mentioned one.

---

### **Using `pdfx` package in LaTeX**

- Be sure to have the latest `pdfx` package available. For that purpose you can simple use the `kpsewhere pdfx.sty` function in Linux to get the path to the file and check the version (open it with an editor). In my case I had an older package and had to update the package (https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfx?lang=en)
- All information are provided in the documentation as well as further thinks such as `how to add the meta keywords`.

For example, I added a new file at the first position using the `input`function (attention: before the document class definition).

```
\input{Pre/Pre_MetaData}
\documentclass[...]
\input{Pre/Pre_Packages}
\input{Pre/Pre_Settings}
```

while in the `Pre_MetaData` file one will find this kind of code (which can be extended according to the documentation of the `pdfx` package:

```
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xmpdata}
 \Title{Your Title of the work}
 \Author{Tobias Holzmann\sep And Others}
 \Keywords{Your\sep Keywords\sep}
 \Publisher{...}
 \Copyright{...}
\end{filecontents*}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
```

If one is using the `pdfx` package at the end of the work (I mean you wrote a book or thesis and realize that you have to build a PDF/A file), it can happen that you have to make a workaround of own generated commands. So I recommend to everybody who directly knows that it has to be a PDF/A file, directly start including the `pdfx package`. In addition - as it is stated in the documentation - it is a good idea to load that package at first position. After that, you can re-compile the document and the PDF/A pdf is generated. Summing up:

- Ensure that you have the latest `pdfx` package installed
- Include the meta data right at the beginning (before the document class starts)
- Include the `pdfx` package at the first place (also read the dependency list: e.g. the `hyperref` package does not have to be included by the user anymore because `pdfx` is loading it...)
- Add the color scheme to your LaTeX project (you will find one in the source files or here http://www.color.org/iccprofile.xalter)
- Remove problems of own defined commands (if ever)
- Compile it with pdflatex (I did it in that way)
- Check it with `veraPDF` and you will probably see a bunch of errors which are summed up and resolved below
- If everything is fine you are done, congrats :)

---

### **Errors with `veraPDF` and `pdfx`**

I realized that while using the first method (`Acrobat Pro`), `preflight` and `veraPDF` gave me a valid PDF/A result while with LaTeX and the `pdfx` package I failed a lot of checks. However, this told me that there are some problems with the `pdfx` package or in general with the PDF written by LaTeX.

I got a range of error messages during the verification of the PDF/A file generated by LaTeX by using `veraPDF` and `preflight`. At the beginning I had more than half million failed checks ~ 543.000. Most of the errors were related to a non-included color scheme (point #4 in the list above). This can be easily resolved by adding the color scheme and done.

Another bunch of errors were tricky to figure out and were related to transparency figures and other features which (now I know it) are not supported by the pdf version 1.4. In my LaTeX project, there are more than 50 eps files that are converted to pdfs by using the `epstopdf` package. Here the problem starts with `pdfx` based on a problem that is introduced by that package. I guess it is a bug and I sent already a message to the creators.

- In any case the `pdfx` package will set the pdf version we create to the version 1.4 which is correct for the PDF/A-1 standard published 2005; cf. ISO 190005-1 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A).
- However, any setting/option one will set for the `pdfx` package will lead to a pdf version 1.4. Even if a specification of PDF/A-2 is done. This should give in fact a pdf version 1.7.
- And here the problem starts because the `epstopdf` generates pdf's which are of pdf version 1.5 while the LaTeX document will be in version 1.4. This is not compatible and the graphic pdfs of version 1.5 do have features that are not supported in version 1.4
- This discrepancy in versions lead to a lot of errors in `veraPDF` with opacity and transparency of figures especially with the `ca` value etc. (https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-validation-profiles/wiki/PDFA-Part-1-rules)

By the way, you can figure out the version of a pdf in Linux by using the `pdfinfo myPDF.pdf` command.

In order to get rid of the problem, one has to hack the `pdfx` package to set the correct version for the pdf. To do so, one has to find the path to the `pdfx.sty` file by using `kpsewhere pdfx.sty` again and open it by using an editor one likes (sudo it):

```
sudo vim /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfx/pdfx.sty
```

Search for that comment - line 750 (in version v1.5.84)

```
%% Hyperref options for PDF/A and PDF/E
```

And add, after the `hyperref` stuff, the following line while changing the version according to the version you would like to have for your pdf.

```
\thepdfminorversion=6  % Corresponds to version 1.6
```

In order to give a better statement of the position in my case I added it to line 815:

```
\ifpdfx@x
 \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \ifxetex
   \expandafter\hypersetup\expandafter{\pdfx@pdfX@opts@xetex}
  \else\ifluatex
   \expandafter\hypersetup\expandafter{\pdfx@pdfX@opts@luatex}
  \else
   \expandafter\hypersetup\expandafter{\pdfx@pdfX@opts@pdftex}
  \fi\fi
 }{%
  \ifxetex
   \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\pdfx@pdfX@opts@xetex]{hyperref}
  \else\ifluatex
   \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\pdfx@pdfX@opts@luatex]{hyperref}
  \else
   \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\pdfx@pdfX@opts@pdftex]{hyperref}
  \fi\fi
 }%
\else
 \ifpdfx@e
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
   \ifxetex
    \expandafter\hypersetup\expandafter{\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@xetex}
   \else\ifluatex
    \expandafter\hypersetup\expandafter{\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@luatex}
   \else
    \expandafter\hypersetup\expandafter{\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@pdftex}
   \fi\fi
  }{%
   \ifxetex
    \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@xetex]{hyperref}
   \else\ifluatex
    \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@luatex]{hyperref}
   \else
    \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@pdftex]{hyperref}
   \fi\fi
  }%
 \else % generating PDF/A or ...
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
   \ifxetex
    \expandafter\hypersetup\expandafter{\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@xetex}%
   \else\ifluatex
    \expandafter\hypersetup\expandafter{\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@luatex}%
   \else
    \expandafter\hypersetup\expandafter{\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@pdftex}%
   \fi\fi
  }{%
   \ifxetex
    \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@xetex]{hyperref}
   \else\ifluatex
    \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@luatex]{hyperref}
   \else
    \expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\pdfx@pdfAE@opts@pdftex]{hyperref}
   \fi\fi
 }%
\fi\fi
\hypersetup{pdfencoding=auto}%  unicode
\expandafter\ifx\csname KV@Hyp@psdextra\endcsname\relax\else
 \hypersetup{psdextra}
\fi
\thepdfminorversion=6  % Corresponds to version 1.6
```

After that save the file and update the TeX environment: `sudo texhash`. Done. Now recompile your pdf and you will get the pdf version you need (use `pdfinfo` to check it). After re-checking the pdf by using `Acrobat Pro -> preflight` the PDF/A file was valid and I was happy. For the `veraPDF` tool, I still get 1 error that is related to font programs `Rule 6.3.4-1` (https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-validation-profiles/wiki/PDFA-Part-1-rules#rule-634-1) but I have no idea what it tells me. Any comment is welcomed here.

[image]

---

### **`pdfx` package**

During my investigation into the `pdfx` package I realized that the authors have a bunch of possible options which are not listed in the documentation. However, the options do not influence anything (as far as I got it); e.g. the `pdf16` option which should change the pdf version to 1.6. However, I realized that the `hyperref` code snipped, which is given above, is the part in which the variable `\thepdfminorversion` is changed to 4 in any case. I wrote it to the creators and hope to get some feedback - maybe one of you is interested too and can figure out more (I am not too familiar with the LaTeX syntax).

---

### **veraPDF**

Just a few notes to the `veraPDF application`.

- On one hand during the analysis of the errors, I was able to figure out the source of the problem
- On the other hand, the Rules description does not give to much information (at least to me). Especially the errors I got based on the different pdf versions (the final pdf file v1.4 and the eps converted pdfs v1.5) did not gave me the direct hint that I have different PDF's with different versions. By the way it was Rule 6.4-1 (https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-validation-profiles/wiki/PDFA-Part-1-rules#rule-64-1) and Rule 6.4-2 (https://github.com/veraPDF/veraPDF-validation-profiles/wiki/PDFA-Part-1-rules#rule-64-2).

I got the idea with the PDF version based on the output of `preflight` -> wrong PDF version and LaTeX which stated some version 1.4 and 1.5 things with my pictures.

Sorry that it is now a long answer but maybe someone can get some new information out of that and can solve the problem. If I will get any feedback from the creators, I will make a comment

Finally: `pdfx` works very well now for my Ph.D. thesis. Thanks for the comments and of course, if you use `lualatex` I guess you can use the way RobtAll was explaining. Great forum, great people! Thanks Tobi

---

### **`pdfx` patch**

Right now I am in contact with Ross Moore and he sent me some patch which is more appropriate than my fix. It is not updated to the official repository right now so I share it here.

https://Holzmann-cfd.com/forums/pdfx.sty

Comment: Just FYI: PDF/A (unlike PDF/X) requires actual space character between words. Compiler `pdflatex` can do PDF/A, and can do PDF/X,, but cannot easily do utf-8, or use Open Type fonts. Compiler LuaLaTeX can do utf-8 and PDF/X, but not PDF/A (no actual spaces). Compiler XeTeX can do utf-8 and PDF/A with issues, but not PDF/X. That's AFAIK.

Comment: One other thing: It's nice to see someone who is writing a dissertation, and who is willing to investigate TeX problems. Too often, dissertation writers visit here, with obvious questions they could have answered themselves, or they simply give up when the answer might be complicated. Makes me wonder how they manage to get their Ph.D.s.

Comment: @RobtAll Possibly their PhDs are not on the topic of LaTeX?

Comment: @cfr No doubt. But often, they are working with TeX templates required by their university, or by some academic publisher. You'd think those things would be routine by now.

Comment: Hi, I am in contact with the `pdfx` editors, just if you are interested. If I will get some new information I will let you know. Right now we exchange the problematic. By the way, most of the people I know - here - do not care about the style of the Ph.D. at all. They write in word 12pt double spacing (looks incredible) and get 100 pages easily. In addition, graphics have 72 dpi, plots are not vectorized etc. I care about that and I like to share my experience; hopefully in order to help others.

Comment: @cfr my phd is not in the topic of latex either but I in my opinion there is always a way to get it work (mostly) :) I guess a lot of people don't want to waste time on things they are not interested as well as they want to take the fruits and do not want to share their fruits.

Comment: Hi all, just one comment. I am in contact with the creators and my fix do the job. However, Morre told me that it is related to the `hyperref` package and he made a bug report in order to get this fixed. Maybe soon, we will have everything correct.

Comment: @Tobi the link to the patch is no longer valid. I am interested in this patch. Can you please fix this?

Comment: Dear @Krishna, sorry for the delay. I wanted to do it earlier. Patch is available again.

Comment: I hope you can resolve the problem. Its already a few month ago and I was in contact with the developers; maybe they already added the patch - or resolved the problem.