# Symbol "№" in cm-super cause problem with PDF/A generation by the meanings of VeraPDF-validator

Tags: pdf-a, type1

At the moment we are trying to produce PDF/A-1b compliant version of our journal issues for the state library.

Journal is mixed language - russian/english, so we use cyrrilic and some specific for russian typographic standarts symbols. Particularly - symbol "№" for numbering the issues and grants of russian funds and so on. For typesetting we use cm-super (Type 1) vector fonts.

The problem is: that symbol (№, \No, \textnumero) generates next "error" (failure) by the meaning of VeraPDF-validator (that probably is used by the library) -

> Specification: ISO 19005-1:2005, Clause: 6.3.6, Test number: 1     For
>   every font embedded in a conforming file and used for rendering, the
>   glyph width information in the font dictionary and in the embedded
>   font program shall be consistent.

Now we are considering as a variant of solution changing the "№" font symbol to something like this:

```
\def\ourNo{N\kern-.05em-\kern-.37em\raise.75ex\hbox{\scriptsize o}\@}
```

It looks similar but not the same as original "№" in Type 1 and when copying as a text from PDF it generates several symbols (N-o) and that's not good. But it works.

Does anyone know that problem and can help with the other solutions?

Here is simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{cmap} - disabling or enabling have no effect on the problem
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
%\usepackage{hyperref} - disabling or enabling have no effect on the problem
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
№
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:**
We also tried with "Save to PS - Distiller" procedure in Acrobat Pro, but it cause the same result at validation by VeraPDF, however Adobe validator (Preflight) shows no error.

**UPDATE2:**
With the help of friens I was redirected to [PDF/A with Linux Libertine und Linux Biolinum using pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402431/pdf-a-with-linux-libertine-und-linux-biolinum-using-pdflatex/410098#410098)
and the solution that works well:

```
%%% Solving \textnumero problem in russian pdflatex
%%% Don't know how to explain why this works
\UndeclareTextCommand{\textnumero}{T2A}
\usepackage{textcomp} %depending on previous font packages this may be second call to package
```

It is probably means that in `textcomp` that symbol is "better" defined then in `fontenc` with `t2aenc.dfu`.

Comment: Does the `cm-super` package help in solving your problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't. We have not tryed without cm-super.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of friens I was redirected to [PDF/A with Linux Libertine und Linux Biolinum using pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402431/pdf-a-with-linux-libertine-und-linux-biolinum-using-pdflatex/410098#410098)
and found the solution that works well:

```
%%% Solving \textnumero problem in russian pdflatex
%%% Don't know how to explain why this works
\UndeclareTextCommand{\textnumero}{T2A}
\usepackage{textcomp} %depending on previous font packages this may be second call to package
```

It is probably means that in `textcomp` that symbol is "better" defined then in `fontenc` with `t2aenc.dfu`.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, colleagues, the solution works well, but as one can see it is just a crutch.
The problem of "bad" symbol is still exists and with the solution above we are changing "bad" one, declared in T2A, on good one, declared in TS1. This, particularly, makes us using additional fontencoding and as result lots of additional fontsymbols are included into pdf-a. It's no good.
So, the question now is - whether it possible to correct T2A (especially with respect to \No symbol) on CTAN?