# pdflatex does not support updated version pdf creation

Tags: pdftex

I am using `pdflatex filename.tex` command to create the PDF document.

But the pdf file produced by default version 1.5.

But i need a `PDF/X-1a` version.

I am using below commands to change the pdf version:

```
\pdfminorversion=5
\pdfobjcompresslevel=5
```

But I am unable to change the PDF version. The below preflight Error report for your reviews. I am highlighting problem found errors.

How to get get PDF/X-1a version through the pdflatex commands.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
```

\usepackage{pdfx}

```
\pdfminorversion=5
\pdfobjcompresslevel=5

\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a `pdfx` package, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616/586 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255480/586

Comment: @Tor I import the package for `\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}` but the file cannot run the error is shown `! Package kvsetkeys Error: Undefined key `draft,pdftex,pdfpagemode=UseNone,book
marks=false,pdfversion=1.3,pdfstartview='.`

Comment: I've never used it myself, so I don't know why that might be. Perhaps if you show a minimal example, someone can give advice.

Comment: Please use this MWE `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
Hellow world
\end{document}`

Comment: @Tor The pdf is produced 1.3 version. I am using the `pdflatex filename.tex` command

Comment: Please edit the MWE into your question, comments have never been a good place for that. That code doesn't throw any errors here, though the `\pdfminorversion=5` doesn't appear to do anything. And as I said, I've never used it, and I don't really know anything about it, so I don't think I can offer any more help.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to find out which package or command in your tex-file destroys the compliance with PDF/A 1a. Maybe you can start with a very easy document and then add packages and content:

First, compile this document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a-1a]{pdfx}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument{}


\end{document}
```

According to Adobe Acrobat Standard V 10 the PDF meets the PDF/A standard. I'm using texlive 2016, up to date.

Then add your packages and some content and find out, which package or content causes the infringement of the standard.

However, according to the manual of pdfx, "1a" is not fully implemented, but e.g. 1b.

That leads to the question: Why do you need "1a"?