# Producing a minimal valid PDF/X-1A document with recent TeXLive

Tags: pdftex, pdfx

I am trying to produce a valid PDF/X1-A document. I'd like to start with the simplest document possible that passes PDF validation. Here is what I have currently, and the current set of errors as reported by PDFBox's `preflight-app-1.8.16.jar`.

I've also tried reusing the examples in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/242303/pdf-x-1a-on-tex-live-2014-for-publishing-with-pod-lightining-source) but I'm getting most of the same errors. Maybe some things changed since ~2015?

I'm sure there's a long list of things that I'm doing wrong, can someone help? Thank you!

minimal.tex:

```
\documentclass[cmyk]{article}

\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Hello, world!

\end{document}
```

minimal.xmpdata:

```
\Title        {Minimal Example}
\Author       {Me, myself and I}
\Copyright    {Copyright \copyright\ 2018 "Me, myself and I, inc."}
\Keywords     {minimal\sep
               pdf\sep
               example}
\Subject      {A minimal example of a valid PDF/X-1A document.}
```

After compiling with `pdflatex` (version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18), output of `preflight`:

```
The fileminimal.pdf is not valid, error(s) :
2.1.3 : Invalid Graphis object, The S entry of the OutputIntent isn't GTS_PDFA1
2.4.2 : Invalid Color space, The operator "K" can't be used with RGB Profile
2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, The operator "g" can't be used without Color Profile
2.4.3 : Invalid Color space, The operator "G" can't be used without Color Profile
2.4.2 : Invalid Color space, The operator "k" can't be used with RGB Profile
2.4.2 : Invalid Color space, The operator "K" can't be used with RGB Profile
2.4.2 : Invalid Color space, The operator "k" can't be used with RGB Profile
2.4.2 : Invalid Color space, The operator "K" can't be used with RGB Profile
2.4.2 : Invalid Color space, The operator "k" can't be used with RGB Profile
2.4.2 : Invalid Color space, The operator "K" can't be used with RGB Profile
7.11 : Error on MetaData, PDF/A identification schema http://www.aiim.org/pdfa/ns/id/ is missing
```

Comment: Your example works fine for after compiling on a up-to-date texlive 2018, preflight says it is ok. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is... Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, just re-ran apt update/upgrade to make sure, everything is up to date. texlive-base package is at 2017.20180305-1. Do you believe things would be different with 18.10 ? Which version of preflight are you using? Thanks for your help!

Comment: The texsystems in the linux distribuations are normally outdated. You need a vanilla tex to have the newest version. I have a current adobe pro on windows.

Comment: Aha. Okay, I will remove all the Ubuntu/Debian packages and install a new TexLive using their installer and will report back. This helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: I still get the same list of issues with a new TeX Live install: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) -- I wonder if it's an issue with preflight, I haven't been able to make the newest version (> 2) of preflight work (some Java classpath issues that are probably out of scope for this question).