# pdf/a - validation problem - The F key is missing

Tags: pdf, pdf-a, convert

I tried to convert my thesis from Latex to required pdf/a - version 2u. However, two problem occured from a validation test.

Firt one: **"The key F is required but missing."**
I failed with googling it, i think that it has maybe something to do with links. I came across one forum, but I do not understand (probably they are not working in LaTeX) - https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1023316
Then, I tried to find the sollution on our forum, but no one had really the same problem. E.g. I tried to use sollution from this post [PDF/A with hyperref on TeX Live 2013](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130201/pdf-a-with-hyperref-on-tex-live-2013), but the validator told me, that I have pdf1.4, not even pdf/A.
Does anybody know, what should I change to get rid of this "F key" or how to deal with it?

Second problem, which is probably not so important: **The document contains hidden, invisible, non-viewable or non-printable annotations.**
I don't know, what they mean by that exactly. Is there a problem with my notes (meaning text starting with %). Does anybody know the sollution?

My code in preambule, packages used are at the end:

```
    \documentclass[openany,hidelinks]{book}  
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
    \usepackage[czech]{babel}  
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}  
    \usepackage{float}   

    \usepackage{graphicx}  
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}  
    \usepackage{color}  
    \usepackage[round]{natbib}  
    \usepackage{hyperref}  
    \usepackage{bookmark}  
    \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}    

    \newcommand{\myand}{\&\ }

    \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}  
    \makeglossaries  

    \useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}  
    \numberwithin{equation}{chapter}  

    \usepackage{longtable}     
    \usepackage{array}  
    \usepackage{regexpatch}  
    \makeatletter  
    \xpatchparametertext\@cline{-}{\cA-}{}{}  
    \usepackage{placeins}   
    \usepackage{booktabs}  
    \usepackage{caption}   

    \usepackage{pdfpages}   

    %for pdfA  
    \usepackage{xmpincl}  
    \usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}  
    \usepackage{lmodern}  
    \usepackage{textcomp}
```

I would be very grateful for every answer! :) Thank you.

The problem is with my bibliography! Another validator gave me exact pages of the problems. And it looks like this: `root/document[0]/pages[54](825 0 obj PDPage)/annots[16](821 0 obj PDAnnot)`
[image: error_1]
 Second error has this description:
`root/document[0]/pages[64](935 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](936 0 objPDContentStream)/operators[556]/font[0](BCVKHY+LMMathSymbols10-Regular)`

`root/document[0]/pages[64](935 0 obj PDPage)/contentStream[0](936 0 objPDContentStream)/operators[611]/font[0](HVVRCK+LMMathSymbols7-Regular)`

Comment: It is impossible to debug something like this without a complete example -- and when you have a complete example you should make an effort to make a *small* complete example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am very sorry, but I do not know what you mean by example, example of what if not of the code. Thanks :)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have edited my post, i hope that I did it the way you meant

Comment: Add option`pdfa` to package `hyperref`. The option adds some few warnings and settings for greater compliance to PDF/A. It also sets the `/F` key in link annotations.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Wow, it helped! The main error is gone, thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 7):

It is sufficent to add option `pdfa` to package `hyperref`. (as suggested by @heikooberdiek)

Answer (score 0):

Received the same warning from veraPDF when using `\usepackage{animate}`. The package helps to insert animated graphs into a document. When I got rid of this line the validation was successful. Hope someone may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that if you are using ACM format (`acmart.cls`) you may need to set the `hyperref` option (i.e., `pdfa`) inside the `acmart.cls` file itself if it is not already set.