# How to get from pdflatex file containing \includegraphics a pdfx file? Is a short and comprehensive manual?

Tags: pdfx

How to get from pdflatex file containing \includegraphics a pdfx file? Where is a short and comprehensive manual? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. Please see if the Q and A at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576/how-to-generate-pdf-a-and-pdf-x would help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I have a manuscript of a book (130MB, a root, 11 chapters,...) . I would like, if possible, to add certain commands without rewriting the whole book.

Comment: Showing some minimal working examples would help people to help you.

Comment: Your question is quite incomprehensible. What should  "pdfx file" be? And what has \includegraphics to do with it?

Comment: As I suggested upper I talk about a book having a root, 11 chapters, bibliography,..., and whose pdf file is 130 MB due to many figures. The figures are included by \includegraphics. I use pdflatex and obtain a pdf file. I want to get a pdfx file.

Comment: I never heard of a pdfx file, I only know the pdfx package.

Comment: AFAIK, pdflatex alone can only make PDF v. 1.5, so you should use an external tool to convert it to PDF/x or use the mentioned `pdfx` package and select one of the several PDF/x variants.